# dropdownlist quicklinks menu in masterpage

Tags: 2010, list, navigation, dropdown

I would like to create a dropdownlist for quicklink navigation in a master page. The quicklink menu will have direct links to a bunch of subsites. This will need to be accessible from all subsites.

I would also like to have the users be able to update/modify that list.

What is the best way to do this?

I was thinking if I could store the links in a global list of some sort so than display them in the dropdownlist?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about left navigation menu - then it's better to modify it's view with CSS and JavaScript. In this case you will be able to take advantage of the standard way of managing navigation.

If you need to display your dropdown list in addition to the existing navigation then custom user control is what I would use. The control I've recently developed looks like this:http://ge.tt/3V5uNQY/v/0

I'm storing the list of the quick links in a SharePoint list because it's the easiest way.

Also, you can take the advantage of the SharePoint modal dialog boxes functionality so the editing process (when clicking on the "Update list") looks like this: http://ge.tt/3spDOQY/v/0